# How can I print a BigInt in JavaScript without losing precision?

Tags: javascript, bigint

For example I have a long integer like BigInt(714782523241122198), is it possible to convert it to a string without losing any digits? I want to do it natively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to either put an `n` after the number, or put it in quotes, since (as currently written) you have a Number, which is bigger than the max number representable in JavaScript, which is 2^53 or 9007199254740992.

```js
console.log(BigInt(714782523241122198).toLocaleString())
console.log(BigInt("714782523241122198").toLocaleString())
console.log((714782523241122198n).toLocaleString())
```

To be clear, what you are currently doing is equivalent to:

```
const x = 714782523241122198
// x has already lost precision!
const y = BigInt(x);
// y was created with an imprecise number
```